# Request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: android, activity

Вот ошибка: 
request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

а вот код:

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {
protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
    final EditText account = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText Login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    // ProgressBar Progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            try {
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String URL = "http://" + account + ".megaplan.ru/" + Login
                        + "&password" + Password;
                Log.i("httpget", URL);
                try {
                    String SetServerString = "";
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget,
                            responseHandler);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Exception", "Exception:" + e);
                } finally {
                }
            } finally {
            }}});}}
```

Если код не рабочий, то хотя бы должна открываться форма, но она не открывается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в манифесте есть строка вида

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

?

А второе - на 4 андроиде как то делать сетевые запросы с gui не принято, ругаться будет сильно.

Comment: Нет, нету этой строки в манифесте :(

Comment: И с ней и без нее не работает. Тестирую я на 2.3.3 версии и на 3 андроиде.

Comment: тогда ещё logcat нужно показывать.

Comment: У меня не запускался мой layout. Причины я не нашла, просто удалила старый и создала новый. И все заработало. Теперь мой запрос отправляется невесть куда )))